# Insert foreign key with trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a database with two tables `GENRES` and `SONGS`. In `GENRES` the `PRIMARY KEY` is `GENRE_NAME`. I want to create a trigger which I can add the primary key of `GENRES` before insert. The one that I've tried doesn't work. It gets me the error 1452

Database,tables and trigger

```
CREATE DATABASE MUSIC_LIBRARY;
USE MUSIC_LIBRARY;

CREATE TABLE GENRES(GENRE_NAME VARCHAR(25),PRIMARY KEY(GENRE_NAME));

CREATE TABLE SONGS(NO INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,GENRE VARCHAR(25),
                   TITLE VARCHAR(25), ARTIST VARCHAR(25), YOUTUBE_URL VARCHAR(50),
                   PRIMARY KEY(NO), FOREIGN KEY(GENRE) REFERENCES GENRES(GENRE_NAME));

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER genre_foreign BEFORE INSERT ON SONGS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE GENRES
SET GENRE_NAME=NEW.GENRE;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The insert I've tried

```
INSERT INTO SONGS(GENRE,TITLE,ARTIST,YOUTUBE_URL)
VALUES("METAL","WAR PIGS","BLACK SABBATH","LINK");
```

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`music_library`.`songs`, CONSTRAINT `songs_ibfk_1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`GENRE`) REFERENCES `genres` (`GENRE_NAME`)) 0.015 sec

I didn't expect this kind of error. It's like I've added more words or something, but it's the same variable type both are `VARCHAR(25)`. Also, I tried it manually without trigger, and It works, so this is why in my opinion this error is weird.

Comment: Do you have value **"METAL"** in you *GENRES* table column*(GENRE_NAME)* ? Could you select this column?

Comment: No , this is what I want to do. Just before the insert  in Songs table, I want to update Genres table with the data from the insert.

Comment: you cant do it, you **must** first add this value in table where you have primary key, and then you can update your foreign key.